# mutual information of two normal random vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, matrix-calculus, mutual-information

I'm dealing with a question that request to calculate the mutual information of two normal random vectors, this is the description:

If $\mathbf X\sim \mathcal N(\mu_X,\Sigma_X),~\mathbf Y\sim \mathcal N(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$ are random vectors with $N$ elements, the covariance matrix of $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y,$ $\Sigma_{XY}$ is
$$\begin{align}\Sigma_{XY}
&=\mathbb{E}[(\mathbf X-\mathbb{E}\mathbf X)(\mathbf Y-\mathbb{E}\mathbf Y)^\mathsf T]\\
&=\left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_X&\mathsf{cov}(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)\\\mathsf{cov}(\mathbf Y,\mathbf X)&\Sigma_Y\end{matrix}\right]\\
&=\left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_X&\boldsymbol \rho\sqrt{|\Sigma_X||\Sigma_Y|}\\\boldsymbol \rho^\mathsf T\sqrt{|\Sigma_Y||\Sigma_X|}&\Sigma_Y\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}$$if we define correlation matrix $$\boldsymbol \rho={{\sf cov}(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)\over \sqrt{|\Sigma_X||\Sigma_Y|}}.$$

Now the PDF of joint distribution $(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)$ is$$\begin{align}
p_{XY}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)
=&\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2N}|\Sigma_{XY}|}}\exp\left(-\frac12\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]^\mathsf T\Sigma_{XY}^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]\right)\\
=&\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2N}(1-|\boldsymbol \rho|^2)|\Sigma_{X}||\Sigma_Y|}}\\
&\times\exp\left(-\frac12\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]^\mathsf T\left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_X&\boldsymbol \rho\sqrt{|\Sigma_X||\Sigma_Y|}\\\boldsymbol \rho^\mathsf T\sqrt{|\Sigma_X||\Sigma_Y|}&\Sigma_Y\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]\right).
\end{align}$$
Also recall the PDF of $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ are $$\eqalign{
p_X(\mathbf x)=\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^N|\Sigma_X|}}\exp\left(-\frac12(\mathbf x-\mu_X)^\mathsf T\Sigma_X^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mu_X)\right),\\
p_Y(\mathbf y)=\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^N|\Sigma_Y|}}\exp\left(-\frac12(\mathbf y-\mu_Y)^\mathsf T\Sigma_Y^{-1}(\mathbf y-\mu_Y)\right).
}$$

The question is, I want to prove that the mutual information of $(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)$ is $$\eqalign{
\mathbb I(\mathbf X,\mathbf Y)&=\int_\mathbf x\int_\mathbf yp_{XY}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\log\left(p_{XY}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\over p_X(\mathbf x)p_Y(\mathbf y)\right)\mathrm d\mathbf x\mathrm d\mathbf y\\
&=-\frac12\log\left(1-|\rho|^2\right).
}$$

Here is my work update to now:
If we denote the exponent parts of $p_{XY}$'s, $p_X$'s and $p_Y$'s by $q_{XY},~q_X$ and $q_Y,$ for simplicity respectively, and coefficient parts by $1/a_{XY},~1/a_X,$ and $1/a_Y.$

First, $$\begin{align}
&\log\left(p_{XY}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\over p_X(\mathbf x)p_Y(\mathbf y)\right)\\
=&\log\left(a^{-1}_{XY}\over a^{-1}_Xa^{-1}_Y\right)+q_{XY}-q_X-q_Y\\
=&\log\left(\sqrt{(2\pi)^N|\Sigma_X|}\sqrt{(2\pi)^N|\Sigma_Y|}\over\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2N}(1-|\boldsymbol \rho|^2)|\Sigma_{X}||\Sigma_Y|} \right)+q_{XY}-q_X-q_Y\\
=&-\frac12\log\left(1-|\rho|^2\right)+q_{XY}-q_X-q_Y.\\
{\rm and}\\
&\int_\mathbf x\int_\mathbf yp_{XY}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\left[-\frac12\log\left(1-|\rho|^2\right)\right]\mathrm d\mathbf x\mathrm d\mathbf y=-\frac12\log\left(1-|\rho|^2\right).
\end{align}$$
Second, $$\begin{align}
&-2\times (q_{XY}-q_X-q_Y)\\
=&\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]^\mathsf T\Sigma_{XY}^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]\\
&-(\mathbf x-\mu_X)^\mathsf T\Sigma_X^{-1}(\mathbf x-\mu_X)-(\mathbf y-\mu_Y)^\mathsf T\Sigma_Y^{-1}(\mathbf y-\mu_Y)\\
=&\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]^\mathsf T\Sigma_{XY}^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]\\
&-\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]^\mathsf T\left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_X&\mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0&\Sigma_Y\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]\\
=&\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]^\mathsf T \left\{\Sigma_{XY}^{-1}-\left[\begin{matrix}\Sigma_X&\mathbf 0\\\mathbf 0&\Sigma_Y\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\right\} \left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf x-\mu_X\\\mathbf y-\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}$$
We need to deal with $\int\int p_{XY}(q_{XY}-q_X-q_Y),$ but it's too hard for me after trying many methods.

Can you help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim #1:** If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d, \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ then
$$
     \mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(X - \mu)] = d
$$
Indeed, the affine transformation $Y = \Sigma^{-1/2}(X - \mu)$ gives $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_d)$, where $I_d$ is $d\times d$ identity matrix. Then,
$$
    (X - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(X - \mu) = \sum_{k = 1}^d Y_k^2 \sim \chi^2(p)
$$
(notice that $Y_k^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$). Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(X - \mu)] = d$

---

Now,
$$
     \int_{\mathbb{R^N}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} p_{XY}(x, y)q_{XY}(x, y)dxdy = -\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[(Z - \mu')^T(\Sigma')^{-1}(Z - \mu')] = -N
$$
where $Z = (X, Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu', \Sigma')$

Finally,
$$
     \int_{\mathbb{R^N}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} p_{XY}(x, y)q_{X}(x)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} p_X(x)q_X(x)dx = -\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[(X - \mu_X)^T\Sigma_X^{-1}(X - \mu)] = -N/2
$$
Similarly,
$$
     \int_{\mathbb{R^N}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} p_{XY}(x, y)q_{Y}(y)dxdy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} p_Y(y)q_Y(y)dy = -\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[(Y - \mu_Y)^T\Sigma_Y^{-1}(Y - \mu)] = -N/2
$$

Thus,
$$
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} p_{XY}(q_{XY} - q_X - q_Y)dxdy = 0
$$

Comment: Very very very thankful! Your answer is intelligent and concise!